# Smarty Error Suppression

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I am trying to do an error suppression without the error_reporting(NULL) while adding values to a variable that may not be set yet. For example:

```
{$var.1 = $var.1 + 10}
```

In this case $var.1 isn't defined yet, in PHP I can use @ infront of the line to ignore error. How can i do this on Smarty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable smarty notice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789102/disable-smarty-notice)

Comment: I dont want to use error_reporting this isnt a duplicate, I dont want to ignore all errors on the template i just want to ignore that explicit error.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok you fetch code to PHP, you can do it this way:

```
$errorReportingLevel = $smarty->error_reporting;
$smarty->error_reporting = 0;
echo $smarty->fetch('index.tpl');
$smarty->error_reporting = $errorReportingLevel;
echo $smarty->fetch('index.tpl');
```

In the first one call you won't get any warnings and in the second one you will.

As far as I know there is no other way. In addition you should really consider removing this warning. Code should be written the way no notices or warnings are displayed - both in PHP ans in Smarty.